# angular service worker with ngCspOnce - Degraded due to: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork)

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, angular-service-worker, nonce

Service Worker is broken since I started injecting nonce from nginx in index.html

as in

```
<app-root ngCspNonce="$requestId"></app-root>
```

following 1) from https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy

The error says hash mismatch obviously due to injecting that nonce.

Wondering what are my options as I don;t wish to cache index.html since the nonce value must be unique every request ? Also option 2) from the Angular document for injecting CSP does not seem practical.

Wondering how do you deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question incase anyone stumbles across:-

Remove `index.html` from `ngsw-config.json` `assetGroup` that way it will not be cached hence not cache busted and the SW can function normally.